# Javascript regex for getting string before question mark if present

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string: `#test` or `#test?params=something`

```
var regExp = /(^.*)?\?/; 
var matches = regExp.exec($(this).data('target'));
var target = matches[1];
console.log(target);
```

I always need to get only `#test.` The function I pasted returns an error if no question mark is found. The goal is to always return `#test` whether there are additional params or not. How do I make a regex that returns this?

Comment: As rule of thumb - you should use direct string modification methods (like split, strpos, substring etc) instead of regex, when there's no specific need for regex. I would go with method suggested by James.

Answer (score 5):

Is that string direct from the current page's URL?

If so, you can simply use:

```
window.location.hash.split('?')[0]
```

If you're visiting http://example.com/#test?params=something, the above code will return "#test".

#### Tests

```
example.com/#test                     -> "#test"
example.com/#test?params=something    -> "#test"
example.com/foo#test                  -> "#test"
example.com                           -> ""
```

Comment: OP asked for a regex specifically, your solution uses split

Answer (score 4):

```
^(.*?)(?=\?|$)
```

You can try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/25

Comment: @Anonymous are there more types of inputs?Can you add them too

Answer (score 2):

Simple alternative:

```
hash = str.substr(0, (str + "?").indexOf("?"));
```

Comment: OP asked for a regex specifically, your solution uses substr

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
var regExp = /^([^?]+)/;
```

This will always return string before first `?` whether or not `?` is present in input.

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fM5kR9/2)

Answer (score 0):

Either I'm missing something or simply:

```
 ^#\w+
```

Seems to do the job for both([this](http://regexr.com/3a3tu) and [this](http://regexr.com/3a3u1)) scenarios